# Pagination works for archive of CPT but throws 404 error for single-cpt.php

Tags: pagination, timber

I can use Timber pagination in `archive-law.php` for the archive page (`/law/page/2`) of my custom post type, "law", but with the same codes in `single-law.php`, the second page (`/law/cpt-post-slug/page/2`) shows the 404 error. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please provide some sample code to enable folks here to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

That’s how it’s supposed to work. Pagination only works for archive templates like `archive.php` or `home.php`, where you have a query with multiple results that can be paginated. It will not work for singular templates like `single.php`.

However, you could use [`next_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link), which display a link to the next or previous post which exists in chronological order from the current post.

In Timber, these functions are available as [`post.next`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#next) and [`post.prev`](https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/#prev). Here’s an example for how you could use it in in a singular template in Twig:

```
{% if post.next %}
    <h3>Next Article</h3>
    <a href="{{ post.next.link }}">{{ post.next.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```